# getting different instances of footnotes

Tags: xslt

I've the below case in my XML.

```
<main>
    <para num="1.12.10">
        since no <page num="138"/>principal.
        <footnoteref linkend="fn855" num="855"/><footnote num="855" id="fn855" number-type="arabic"></footnote>
    </para>
    <para num="1.12.11">
        In other pl<footnoteref linkend="fn857" num="857"/>
        <footnote num="857" id="fn857" number-type="arabic">
        </footnote>short of the fraud of the agent.
        <footnoteref linkend="fn860" num="860"/>
        <footnote num="860" id="fn860" number-type="arabic"></footnote><footnoteref linkend="fn861" num="861"/><footnote num="861" id="fn861" number-type="arabic">
            <para>At [8-209].</para>
        </footnote>
    </para>
    <para num="1.12.12">
        Indeed, in some non-property cases such as
        <footnoteref linkend="fn862" num="862"/>
        <footnote num="862" id="fn862" number-type="arabic">
            <para>
                <case>[1896] 2 Ch 743</case>.
            </para>
        </footnote>
    </para>
</main>
```

and from `footnotes template` I use the below.

```
    <xsl:template match="footnote">    
    <xsl:if test="preceding::page[1]">
           <xsl:variable name="op">&#60;</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="cl">&#62;</xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="concat($op,'?pb label=',$apos,preceding::page[1]/@num,$apos,'?',$cl)"/>

           </xsl:if>
<div class="tr_footnote">
            <div class="footnote">
                <sup>
                <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:text>ftn.</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:text>#f</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>tr_ftn</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
                    </a>
                </sup>

             <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

and i get the below output

```
&lt;?pb label='138'?&gt;<div class="tr_footnote">
                <div class="footnote">
                    <sup>
                        <a name="ftn.855" href="#f855" class="tr_ftn">855</a>
                    </sup>a</div>
            </div>&lt;?pb label='138'?&gt;<div class="tr_footnote">
                <div class="footnote">
                    <sup>
                        <a name="ftn.857" href="#f857" class="tr_ftn">857</a>
                    </sup>b</div>
            </div>&lt;?pb label='138'?&gt;<div class="tr_footnote">
                <div class="footnote">
                    <sup>
                        <a name="ftn.860" href="#f860" class="tr_ftn">860</a>
                    </sup>c</div>
            </div>&lt;?pb label='138'?&gt;<div class="tr_footnote">
                <div class="footnote">
                    <sup>
                        <a name="ftn.861" href="#f861" class="tr_ftn">861</a>
                    </sup>At [8-209].</div>
            </div>&lt;?pb label='138'?&gt;<div class="tr_footnote">
                <div class="footnote">
                    <sup>
                        <a name="ftn.862" href="#f862" class="tr_ftn">862</a>
                    </sup>[1896] 2 Ch 743.
            </div>
            </div>
```

but i want the output as below.

```
&lt;?pb label='138'?&gt;<div class="tr_footnote">
                <div class="footnote">
                    <sup>
                        <a name="ftn.855" href="#f855" class="tr_ftn">855</a>
                    </sup>a</div>
            </div><div class="tr_footnote">
                <div class="footnote">
                    <sup>
                        <a name="ftn.857" href="#f857" class="tr_ftn">857</a>
                    </sup>b</div>
            </div><div class="tr_footnote">
                <div class="footnote">
                    <sup>
                        <a name="ftn.860" href="#f860" class="tr_ftn">860</a>
                    </sup>c</div>
            </div><div class="tr_footnote">
                <div class="footnote">
                    <sup>
                        <a name="ftn.861" href="#f861" class="tr_ftn">861</a>
                    </sup>At [8-209].</div>
            </div><div class="tr_footnote">
                <div class="footnote">
                    <sup>
                        <a name="ftn.862" href="#f862" class="tr_ftn">862</a>
                    </sup>[1896] 2 Ch 743.
            </div>
            </div>
```

i.e. the first footnote following the `page number` should have `pb label` tag, the footnote location can be ignored. i.e. the footnote can be anywhere in the XML but the first footnote following para should get `pb label` tag and rest should be ignored.

please let me know how can i do it.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the `<page>` element?

Comment: Hi @helderdarocha, it is in the 3rd line of my XML

Comment: Where do you generate those divs? Please add your entire XSLT stylesheet if possible.

Comment: Are you really trying to print `&lt;?pb label=''?&gt;`? Or is it a processing instruction (such as `<?pb label=''?>`) that you are trying to print?

Comment: it is a processing instruction, as `<?pb label=''?>`

Comment: You can create one with: `<xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">` and any text contents.

Comment: ok but that is not my question

Comment: Your text is appearing several times because it is being called inside a template which is processed several times. The solution would be to place it in a template that would be called once (ex: `main`).

Comment: any example or sample on how to do it. please

Comment: Yes. Since you only posted one template, I have to assume another one, at least. I'll post an example. I think I understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your processing instruction repeats many times because it is being called in a template that is processed many times. If it should only occur once, you should print it inside a template that is called only once (such as a template for `main`).

It also seems you are trying to print a processing instruction. It's easier to do that using `xsl:processing-instruction`. So you could test for a preceding `page` element in a `main` or root template and process only those footnotes (you will have to decide what to do with the footnotes that do not have a preceding page):

```
<xsl:if test="//footnote[preceding::page]">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
        <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//footnote/preceding::page[1]/@num"/>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//footnote[preceding::page]"/>
</xsl:if>
```

I'm assuming you only have *one* `page` element. If you have many, the predicate *test* will still match all footnotes that have *any* preceding `page` element (the `[1]` predicate you placed for `page` in the *test* will not change that - testing for the existence of a *previous* `page` or any preceding `page` is the same) but will *select* the *value* of the *previous* one.

Your `footnote` template (which will be called many times) only has to deal with the contents of the footnote itself. You can make it simpler using *attribute value templates* for processing or simply the value of the string you want and not have to use `xsl:attribute`:

```
<xsl:template match="footnote">
    <div class="tr_footnote">
        <div class="footnote">
            <sup><a name="{@id}" href="#f" class="tr_ftn"><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></a></sup>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a full stylesheet that uses those templates and also does something with some other nodes which are present in your source code. Maybe you want to do something like this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="main">    
        <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
        <xsl:if test="//footnote[preceding::page]">
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
                <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="//footnote/preceding::page/@num"/>
                <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            </xsl:processing-instruction>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="para//footnote[preceding::page]"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p title="{@num}"><xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(name() = 'footnote')]"/></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="footnoteref">
        <sup><a href="{@linkend}"><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></a></sup>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="footnote">
        <div class="tr_footnote">
            <div class="footnote">
                <sup><a name="{@id}" href="#f" class="tr_ftn"><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></a></sup>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @helderdarocha, when i applied this, but still there is repetition of the footnote numbres, i've uploaded my XML and XSLT [here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/p3dPKW), can you please look into it. Thanks.

Comment: you can get the exact result what i get if u see paste the XML and XSLT [here](http://fiddle.frameless.io/)

Comment: You question doesn't reproduce your actual problem correctly. If you have *many* `page` elements, and need one processing instruction for *each one* (not only one) then you can't use `preceding::page` since that will match all of them (as I noted in the third paragraph above). In this case, you will need to use completely different approach. Perhaps you can use that information to rewrite a new question describing your problem better.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to print one processing instruction for *each* `page` element. They should be printed immediately before the first footnote element that appears after the *last* `page` element, until the *next* `page` element appears, which will clear everything and start again. You actually need to use grouping (group the footnotes by the *last* occurrence of `page`). If this is your question, try to write an example case (a conceptual example with maybe 2 or 3 `page` elements and 1 or 2 footnotes each) that will expose that problem.

Comment: sure give me few minutes

Comment: Take your time. It's better to dedicate some time to make e good and complete example that describes well your actual problem (in code and in words). The chance of getting better answers will be higher.

Comment: Hi @helderdarocha I've updated my new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543351/matching-the-following-and-call-template)

Comment: It's still too complex, and all your page elements are still *before* all your footnotes. That doesn't reproduce the problem well (you might get other answers which won't solve your problem). I changed it a bit and placed some footnotes before some pages (so you can *group* footnotes per page). You still need to add your expected result (in relation to the source) and a XSLT template at least.

Comment: Check the question and edit it to include this information (and to adapt it if you think it's necessary)