# matching the following and call template

Tags: xslt, grouping, xslt-2.0, processing-instruction

This is a simplified XML which exposes the general structure of the problem I have.

```
<chapter num="07">
    <title>
        <page num="703"/>
        ... text (mixed content) ...
    </title>

    <page num="704"/>
    <section level="sect1">
        <title>...text...</title>
        <para num="7.1.1">... a lot of text (mixed content)...</para>
    </section>
    <section level="sect1">
        <title>... text... </title>
        <para num="7.2.1">Some text...
            <footnoteref linkend="fn3" num="3"/>
            <footnote num="3" id="fn3"> ... mixed content ...</footnote> 
            ...more text...
        </para>

        <page num="705"/>
        <section level="sect2">
            <title>...</title>
            <para num="7.2.2">... text ...
                <footnoteref linkend="fn4" num="4"/>
                <footnote num="4" id="fn4">...</footnote> 
                ... more text ...
                <footnoteref linkend="fn5" num="5"/>
                <footnote num="5" id="fn5">...</footnote> 
                ... more text ...
            </para>
            <para num="7.2.5">...

                <page num="706"/>... 

                <footnoteref linkend="fn6" num="6"/>
                <footnote num="6" id="fn6"> ... </footnote>
            </para>
            <para num="7.2.6">... some text
                <footnoteref linkend="fn7" num="7"/>
                <footnote num="7" id="fn7"> ... </footnote>  
            </para>
        </section>
    </section>
</chapter>
```

I have to place one processing instruction `<?pb label='`*page number*`'?>` *before* the first `<footnote>` matching the last preceding `<page>`. It should appear only once and the *page number* should be the same as the value in the `num` attribute of the last `<page>` element that appeared.

For example, if I process the source above, I expect to generate in my result document *one* `<?pb label='704'?>` immediately before `<footnote num="3">`, *one* `<?pb label='705'?>` immediately before `<footnote num="4">` (grouping footnotes 4 and 5), and *one* `<?pb label='706'?>` immediately before `<footnote num="6">` (grouping footnotes 6 and 7). There is a template to process the `<footnote>` elements and they are placed together at the end of each page, preceded by the processing instruction (the `<footnoteref>` elements stay where they are).

My XSL is [here](http://pastebin.com/ENjcKmqK). Since it is too big, I'm unable to paste it here.

I'm getting duplicates in the footnote processing instructions (the pb labels). There should be a pblabel only before the first `footnote` following the last `page` tag. I tried matching with `preceding::page` but it didn't work. The the same processing instruction is being repeated multiple times. For example: `<?pb label='706'?>` should appear only once above `footnote 6` because it is the first `footnote` following `page 706`.

Comment: Your example is still too complicated. I simplified your source, removing the irrelevant code for the question, and placing footnotes in different pages so you can have a more complete test case. But you still need to show your expected result. I believe you can write a small XSLT reproducing the problem (using the source above). Your full XSLT won't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without doing a time consuming analysis, but try changing this `xsl:if` (in `match="footnote" mode="footnote"`):

```
    <xsl:if test="preceding::node()[page[1]]">
        <xsl:variable name="op">&#60;</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="cl">&#62;</xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="concat($op,'?pb label=',$apos,preceding::page[1]/@num,$apos,'?',$cl)"/>

    </xsl:if>
```

To this:

```
    <xsl:if test="(preceding::page|preceding::footnote)[last()][self::page]">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb" select="concat('label=''',preceding::page[1]/@num,'''?')"/>
    </xsl:if>
```

Kinda strange that you're trying to output XML processing instructions when your output method is HTML (which would have SGML processing instructions).